# In Facebook share dialog, can we make title and description readonly?

Tags: facebook, dialog, share, facebook-sharer

In the Facebook share dialog, the video title and description are click-able, and editable. Is there a way to disable this so it's Read-Only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible in any way, currently. I think it's good idea not to give this option to make it readOnly

Answer (score 0):

For example you want to share players earned points with this dialog. In this approach this functionality becomes logic.